# groupby this or that

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

Bear with me for this one, I've been breaking my head over this for hours.

Consider these data

```
np.random.seed(2)
apples = np.random.randint(10,20,9)
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':list('aabbcdeee'), 'addr':list('mmznjjkkx'), 'apples':apples})[['name','addr','apples']]
```

If `name` is the same then it's the same person, if `addr` is the same, it's also the same person. I want to count the number of apples each person has. Normally, this would be trivial:

```
In [50]: df[['apples', 'name']].groupby('name').sum()
    Out[50]:
      apples
name
a         36
b         28
c         18
d         17
e         38
```

or  `df[['apples', 'addr']].groupby('addr').sum()` since they should return the same output.
**BUT**, addr `j` entered her name as `c` and `d`, while name `b`entered her address as `z` and `n` while `e` entered the address correctly twice but messed up the 3rd time. As a result, both of the above `groupby` operations *undercount* the number of apples some people own. The ideal output is:

```
In [52]: %paste
pd.DataFrame({'name':list('aabbcceee'), 'addr':list('mmnnjjkkk'), 'apples':apples}).groupby('name').apples.sum()

## -- End pasted text --
Out[52]:
name
a    36
b    28
c    35
e    38
Name: apples, dtype: int32
```

I can identify the indexes with erronous addresses or names using sets:

```
sameNames = df.name[df.name.duplicated()].index
sameAddr = df.addr[df.addr.duplicated()].index
sameNameORaddr = df.name[(df.name.duplicated() | df.addr.duplicated())].index
```

so that the mistakes are here:

```
In [47]: sameNameORaddr.difference(sameNames).union(sameNameORaddr.difference(sameAddr))
Out[47]: Int64Index([2, 3, 4, 5, 8], dtype='int64')
```

but I can't figure out how to use this to perform the `groupby`. I was thinking of trying to assign new names that can correctly identify duplicate names or addresses but can't figure out how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can create a mapping from address to name. Then overwrite the names with this mapping and perform your `GroupBy` as normal:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates('addr').set_index('addr')['name']
df['name'] = df['addr'].map(s)

res = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['apples'].sum()

print(res)

  name  apples
0    a      36
1    b      28
2    c      35
3    e      38
```

The initial `drop_duplicates` by `addr` works under the assumption the *first* address entered for any `name` is the correct one.

Comment: this is a faster, simpler, and perhaps more pliable solution but for some reason, the one by @Abhi finds more groups. I think both answers should be tested when applying to one's data because depending on the complexity they may yield different answers.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
df['group'] = df.groupby('addr').ngroup()

d = {'name':'first','apples':'sum'}
df1 = df.groupby('name',as_index=False).sum().groupby('group').agg(d)

df1 = df1.sort_values('name').reset_index(drop=True)

print (df1)

# Output:

  name  apples
0   a    36
1   b    28
2   c    35
3   e    38
```

#### Explanation:

First use [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to number each group in the `addr` col

```
df['group'] = df.groupby('addr').ngroup()

  name addr apples group
0   a   m    18     2
1   a   m    18     2
2   b   z    16     5
3   b   n    12     3
4   c   j    18     0
5   d   j    17     0
6   e   k    12     1 
7   e   k    11     1 
8   e   x    15     4
```

Then groupby with name and sum `df.groupby('name',as_index=False).sum()` it returns

```
   name  apples group
 0  a     36     4
 1  b     28     8
 2  c     18     0
 3  d     17     0
 4  e     38     6
```

Now same address rows will have same group number so you groupby again on the `group` column and use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) function with `apples = 'sum'` and `name = first or last` to keep the first/last instances of name.

```
d = {'name':'first','apples':'sum'}
df1 = df.groupby('name',as_index=False).sum().groupby('group').agg(d)
```

Then just sort values and reset index to get the output.

Comment: could you elaborate on the mechanics of this?

Comment: keeps failing at the call to `ngroup()`: `'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ngroup'`

Comment: Maybe it's my pandas: `pd.__version__
Out[8]: '0.18.1'`?

Comment: @GeneBurinsky Yes. It's only available from  `version 0.20.2`. You can update.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky Use this `df['group'] = df.groupby('addr').grouper.group_info[0]` instead of `df.groupby('addr').ngroup()`